# how to get Observablelist from other controller?

Tags: java, javafx-8, observablelist

I have an controller class in which I am drawing a `Polygon` and moving it with the help of my anchor class for which I have made a `Observablelist<Anchor>` and I am trying to get it in other controller of same type but it is giving me error that incompatible type "`hexagonController.Observablelist<Anchor>` can not be converted to `ObservableList<SecondFrame.Anchor>`"

The code that I made in hexagon controller is

```
public  ObservableList<Anchor> getAnchors(){
    return this.anchors;

}
```

this is the point where I am getting it

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/Hexagon.fxml"));
Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
HexagonController controller= fxmlLoader.<HexagonController>getController();
anchors=FXCollections.observableArrayList(controller.getAnchors());
Stage stage = new Stage();
stage.setTitle("Edytuj klienta");
stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));
stage.show();
```

Comment: Capitalization on the L in ObservableList? in the error it says Observablelist, lower case "l" in "list"

Comment: Tha only line in your code that could yield this compile time error is `anchors = FXCollections.observableArrayList(controller.getAnchors());`. However lacking a `observableArrayList` method in `FXCollections` that takes `ObservableList` as parameter the code you've posted ***cannot*** yield such an error... (at least using the standard compiler)